# How to build my own js library with webpack4?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I use webpack4 to build my own js library, and add the build js to my page.

when I type window.wwsLogin(the libraryName) on the console, It turned out to `be Module {default: {…}, __esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}`

and `window.wwsLogin.default` is the right output, but i just want to use it with `window.wwsLogin`, how to fix it?

this is my webpack config:

```
entry: './lib/index.js',

output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    library: 'wwsLogin',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
    globalObject: "typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this",
},

resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
},

mode: 'production',

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: 'babel-loader',
        },
    ],
},
```

and this is my .babelrc:

```
{
"presets": ["@babel/env"],
"plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",  "add-module-exports"]}
```

[image: this is the console output]

and i use es6 to import and export.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your library is available as a module, so you can use `import` to use it in other code. If you want `window.wwsLogin` to be available in the global scope, you have to add it first, you could do that from the library code.

Add something like this to your library

```
   window.wwsLogin = this
```

(Depending on what your library looks like)

Comment: thanks for your advice, and I and added `libraryExport: 'default',`to webpack output config and solved this problem.